# AOP spring aspect not triggered

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-aop

Hi i have a problem with an Aspect that is not triggered and i don't know why. Here is how it is my project:

The annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;


@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Profiled {
}
```

The aspect:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;



@Aspect
public class ProfiledAspect {
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProfiledAspect.class);
private final String TIME_UNIT = "ms";

@Around("@annotation(annotation)")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Profiled annotation) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Object result = pjp.proceed();
    long end= System.nanoTime();

    long duration = end - start;

    System.out.println("Duration: " + duration + "nano secs.");
    return result;
}
}
```

Here is my config class:

```
import com.myexample.aop.ProfiledAspect;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;


@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myexample"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ProfiledAspect profiledAspect(){
    return new ProfiledAspect();
}

}
```

Here is my class where i am using the annotation to trigger the aspect:

```
import com.myexample.aop.Profiled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TestAnnotationClass {

@Profiled
public void testAnnotationClass()  {
 System.out.println("test profile annotation");
}


}
```

Here are the maven dependency that i am using for the AOP thing

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any idea why the aspect is not triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Is the Profiled Annotation missing in the @Around

```
@Around("@annotation(com.example.Profiled)")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Profiled annotation) throws Throwable {
    ...
}
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work ... and the annotation is there. more over there is a mistake, because if you put together the @Around("@annotation(com.example.Profiled)")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Profiled annotation) with the annotation as method parameter too it will not compile

Comment: Yes, because it should be `@annotation(annotation)` if your want to bind the annotation to the advice parameter. @vcetinick, it would be better to test whatt you post. ;-)

Comment: It is a mistake in my post, i tested that too, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can make the aspect also a `@Component` and have it picked up by component scan instead of instantiating it manually.

Another idea is to use `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)` because your target class does not implement an interface which could be proxied by a JDK proxy, but a simple class. For that you need a CGLIB proxy.